# Powershell: ExecutionPolicy is unable to be read/set

Tags: powershell

I was trying to run a powershell script (which I have run before) and received the following error:
**Authorizationmanager Check Failed**

I figured it was the Execution Policy, so ran:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

I then received:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy : Initialization failure
>   At line:1 char:20
>   + set-executionpolicy <<<<  unrestricted
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], ManagementException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.ManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand

The same initialization error occurs for Get-ExecutionPolicy

Some basic commands seem to work fine, such as:

> Write-Output "hi"

Can anyone suggest a fix?

**Note:** This is on Windows XP

**Update:** If I run the contents of ascript from within the powershell command prompt, it works. I only get the errors if it is run as a script. Also, Get-ExecutionPolicy and Set-ExecutionPolicy still fail from within the powershell prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the error was due to a problem with the WMI repository. I was able to repair the repository running the following command:

**Note**: This is for Windows XP

```
rundll32 wbemupgd, UpgradeRepository
```

Once this was run, I was successfully able to execute Get-ExecutionPolicy, and other powershell scripts again.

A [couple](http://www.myitforum.com/articles/1/view.asp?id=11257) of [links](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/GeneralPurposeLanguages/powershell-wmiobject-and-a-corrupt) that detail repairing the WMI Repository.

Comment: If you're running Vista or Windows 7, run this command: winmgmt  /salvagerepository

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are running the console as admin [Right click] then [click] "run as administrator" when you run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`.

Comment: If he didn't have the right privledges, he would get an unauthorized error.

Comment: This is on a Windows XP, logged in as a member of the Adminstrators group.

Answer (score 0):

Another very common case (I think this only applies post-XP), is where the .ps1 file has been 'blocked' after being downloaded from an untrusted location.

Solution: open the 'Properties' of the file in Windows Explorer, and on the 'General' tab click 'Unblock', then 'Apply' or 'OK'.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential reason for this error (seen on Windows Server 2012) is that the Windows Management Instrumentation service is not running.

Starting and running the service allows for Get-ExecutionPolicy to run, and then Set-ExecutionPolicy.